# Get root url in asp.net regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

I wonder if I can do this code in one regex:

```
    String url = "ftp://url.com.other/asd";
    url = Regex.Replace( url, "(https|http|ftp|file)://","");
    int index = url.IndexOf("/");
    if (index != -1)
    {
        url = url.Remove(index);
    }
    //result should be: url.com.other
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class for this, more specifically the [`Host`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://url.com.other/asd");
String hostname = uri.Host;
```